# Count Distinct Values in a List of Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, count

I just imported the values from a .csv file to a list of lists, and now I need to know how many distinct users are there. The file itself looks like to following:

```
[['123', 'apple'], ['123', 'banana'], ['345', 'apple'], ['567', 'berry'], ['567', 'banana']]
```

Basically, I need to know how many distinct users (first value in each sub-list is a user ID) are there (`3` in this case, over 6,000 after doing some Excel filtering), and what are the frequencies for the food itself: `{'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'berry': 1}`.

Here is the code I have tried to use for distinct values counts (using Python 2.7):

```
import csv
with open('food.csv', 'rb') as food:
    next(food)
    for line in food:
        csv_food = csv.reader(food)
        result_list = list(csv_follows)

result_distinct = list(x for l in result_list for x in l)

print len(result_distinct)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[x[0] for x in result_list]` to get a list of all the ids. Then you create a `set`, that is all list of all unique items in that list. The length of the set will then give you the number of unique users.

```
len(set([x[0] for x in result_list]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that is what a `Counter` is all about:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

result_list = []

with open('food.csv', 'rb') as food:
    next(food)
    for line in food:
        csv_food = csv.reader(food)
        result_list += list(csv_follows)

result_counter = Counter(x[1] for x in result_list)

print len(result_counter)
```

A `Counter` is a special dictionary. Internally the dictionary will contain `{'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'berry': 1}` so you can inspect all elements with their counts. `len(result_counter)` will give **the number of distinct elements** whereas `sum(result_counter.values())` will **give the total number of elements**).

**EDIT**: apparently you want to count the number of *distinct* **users**. You can do this with:

```
len({x[0] for x in result_list})
```

The `{.. for x in result_list}` is *set comprehension*.

Answer (score 0):

To get the distinct users, you can use a set:

```
result_distinct = len({x[0] for x in result_list})
```

And the frequencies, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
freqs = collections.Counter([x[1] for x in result_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#types-set),

```
import operator

lists = [['123', 'apple'], ['123', 'banana'], ['345', 'apple'], ['567', 'berry'], ['567', 'banana']]
nrof_users = len(set(map(operator.itemgetter(0), lists)))

print(nrof_users)
# 3
```

For the second question, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),

```
import collections
import operator

result = collections.Counter(map(operator.itemgetter(1), lists))

print(result)
# Counter({'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'berry': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[[0, 1],[0, 3],[1, 3],[3, 4],[3, 6],[4, 5],[4, 7],[5, 7],[6, 4]]
K = []
for _ in range(len(A)):
    K.extend(A[_])
print(set(K))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

In python `extend` function extends the list instead of appending it that's what we need and then use `set` to print distinct values.